# Given sets A and B such that A ⊆ B, write down A ∪ B in a simplified form.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Here's how I did it:

Let A = {1,2,3}
Let B = {1,2,3,4,5}

Since A ∪ B, everything in A would also be in B thus the simplified form would be B?

If it's wrong, please let me know how to go about this, thanks.

Comment: This seems to be basically a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1229234/how-can-i-prove-if-a-subseteq-b-then-a-cup-b-b). (And I would not be surprised if you find several other posts about the same question.)

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 5):

You are correct. Since all elements in $A$ are also in $B$, there is no need to write down $A \cup B$ (except when e.g. specifically needed for proving a theorem) as that would simply be $B$ again.

You do not even need the examples, you can do this in a fully general way. Since for every $a \in A$, we know that also $a \in B$, it follows that the set $A \cup B = \{x | x \in A \lor x \in B \}$ is equal to $\{x | x \in B \}$, which is just $B$.